# Routing two not-node points and road side with pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting, routing

I'm starting to use pgrouting and I have a couple of problems. In my project I have a lot of points which are near one of the road sides.
I'd like to know how I can route two of these points since they aren't nodes of the topology. This route have to consider the road side in which they are and finish in this side and not in the other one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think pgrouting has such functionality, but you can find it in our RW Net 4 library (www.routeware.dk)

Answer (score 1):

Pgrouting  supports one way routing , see http://pgrouting.org/docs/howto/oneway.html
Or you can use TRSP see: http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/trsp/doc/index.html

I think data has to have own line for each side of road to work